# Finding domain of binomial function under square roots

Tags: functions, binomial-coefficients

What are the conditions that must be taken care of when finding the domain of the function $\sqrt {\binom {x^2+4x}{2x^2+3} }$ ?

Comment: What is $x$? $x \in \mathbb N$?

Comment: No nothing as such is mentioned in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i)$$  x\in \mathbb N$$

ii) $$2x^2+3\le x^2+4x$$
$$x^2-4x+3\le 0$$
$$(x-1)(x-3)\le0$$
Answer: $x\in \{1,2,3\}$